# I did a clusterward analysis - how to add a column with the results to my original data

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, traminer

I did a cluster ward analysis from `OM` (optimal matching) distances obtained with `TraMineR`.

```
R>library (cluster)
R>clusterward<- agnes (test.om,dis=TRUE, method="ward") # where test is my dataset
```

I chose 6 clusters

```
R> cluster6<- cutree(clusterward, k=6)
```

I tried to add a cloumn to my dataset :

```
R> groups = cutree(clusterward, k=6)
R> result = cbind(clusterward, k=6, groups)
```

And i received the following error message :

```
Avis dans cbind(clusterward, k = 6, groups) :
    number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

How can I solve this problem ??

Comment: What is `OM`? Show us your `test` dataset (or a sample). Construct a reproducible example. Show us `clusterward`, `groups` and `result`.

Comment: Seriously **read the documentation on `cbind`**. That line makes no sense. http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cbind.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that clusterward is not your dataset, it is the results of the clustering. Suppose you have a data.frame containing all your data (individual informations) called "mydata", then you can use:

```
mydata <- cbind(mydata, groups)
```

Or (if you use the first command)

```
mydata <- cbind(mydata, cluster6)
```

Please note that you should use diss=TRUE (and not dis=TRUE) in your agnes command.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `k=6` in the `cbind` looks odd and is most likely not what you want to have. Without an example, just the advice, print each element that you want to `cbind`and check if this is really what you want to put. I think you will see quite fast, that there shouldn't be `k=6` in this command (and I am not sure what is stored in `clusterward`, if those parts match).

As I understood it, shouldn't it be something like `cbind(test.om,groups)`?